# Graphics with wrong sizes in table

Tags: tables, graphics

I want to make a table from images of specific size (`2cm`) in PDF format. But in case of using `article` document class I got larger images. I tried to use `minimal` class and got right sizes, but invisible table borders.

There is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{minimal}

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\ABTile}{\includegraphics[height=2cm, width=2cm]{./AB.png}}
\newcommand{\AvTile}{\includegraphics[height=2cm, width=2cm]{./Av.png}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{|p{\tileSize}|p{\tileSize}|}
        \hline
        \ABTile    & \ABTile \\
        \AvTile    & \AvTile \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[Result with article class (pdf)](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/15641213/tiles%20%28article%29.pdf)

[Result with minimal class (pdf)](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/15641213/tiles%20%28minimal%29.pdf)

Is there any way to make table with right size?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8963940/wrong-sizes-in-latex?noredirect=1) was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: It may be that your images have additional whitespace at the top/bottom, causing you to use something like `\\[-1.2cm]`.

Comment: You should add `keepaspectratio` to your `\includegraphics` statements - otherwise the graphics will get distored.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a special column descriptor (`@{}`) which can be used in the tabular definition. It replaces the spacing with whatever you put inside the curly braces (so leave blank to have no space). Try replacing

```
\begin{tabular}{|p{\tileSize}|p{\tileSize}|}
```

with

```
\begin{tabular}{|@{}c@{}|@{}c@{}|}
```

That is, wrap the `c` or `p` with `@{}` on either side to make 0 space on both sides.

Comment: Ok. It solves problem with width. But height is still wrong.

Comment: Using \\[-1.2cm] before each new row helps. Not good but acceptable solution. Thank you.

Comment: @citxx Try putting `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.5}` before the tabular environment. You can change the number (0.5) to fine tune the spacing. It's a bit more elegant (and simple) of a solution I think...